# TypeError: errors.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I am working on a nodejs app. And I am getting this

> TypeError: errors.forEach is not a function

error on my route file.

The code works fine without the promise function(). But as soon as I add the promise function. It throws the  error

```js
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  req.checkBody('email', 'Oops! A valid email is required.').isEmail() //validate email

  var errors = req.validationErrors()

  //look for already registered on database
  //create a global variable called globalvar
  var globalvar = {}; // Globally scoped object
  //start function
  var promise = new Promise(function findemail(resolve, reject) { //using promise
    const find = db.collection('users').doc(email);
    const doc = find.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  promise.
  then(function findemail() {
    globalvar.bool = true;
    console.log('email does not exists');
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
  }).
  catch(function findemail() {
    globalvar.bool = false;
    console.log('email exists');
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
  });


  //If no errors are found continue registration
  if (!errors && globalvar.bool == true) {
    //add user data
  }
  //DISPLAY ERRORS TO USER
  else {
    var error_msg = ''
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
      error_msg += error.msg + '<br>'
    })
    req.flash('error', error_msg)
    res.render('signup', {
      title: 'Registration Page',
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: ''
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: you should have to use async , await in  yours app for promise resolving .

Comment: Already used. But it is showing the same error.

Comment: Why does `var errors = req.validationErrors();` appear in three different places?  If you want to know why `errors.forEach()` doens't work, then do some debugging and insert a `console.log(errors)` and see what is exactly is.  Apparently, it's not an object that has a `.forEach()` method.  Only you can determine what it actually is since you don't show us the code for `req.validationErrors()`.

Answer (score 0):

check the variable type of **errors** variable, it should be an **array, map, or set**.